# how to loop in ggplot2 to get many plots per page

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to loop a piece of code that produces graph by ggplot2. My data set looks like the example "prot", juts prot is one accession and in the original data I have many more accessions.
For single accession it looks nice. Just with the looping, I thought that it will place one iteration per one page in .pdf
but it doesn't. This single plot already creates combined plots, so I don't know now how and where to place facet_wrap or facet_grid?
or maybe there is other solution?
help, please help.

```
 'library(ggplot2)

 ggplot(prot, aes(factor(genotype), value, fill = Light)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
 scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")




  '> prot
   Accession genotype          variable      value Light
  966    AT1G01050       WT    ML_WT_Dejan_05   219971.1    ML
  2828   AT1G01050       WT    ML_WT_Dejan_06   286308.6    ML
  4690   AT1G01050       WT    ML_WT_Dejan_14  1177873.5    ML
  6552   AT1G01050        m     ML_m_Dejan_08   861982.0    ML
  8414   AT1G01050        m     ML_m_Dejan_10  3786163.0    ML
  10276  AT1G01050        m     ML_m_Dejan_11  1289267.7    ML
  12138  AT1G01050        f     ML_f_Dejan_01   400419.3    ML
  14000  AT1G01050        f     ML_f_Dejan_04   929297.2    ML
  15862  AT1G01050        f     ML_f_Dejan_09 12245991.9    ML
  17724  AT1G01050     ntrc  ML_ntrc_Dejan_02   785773.5    ML
  19586  AT1G01050     ntrc  ML_ntrc_Dejan_03   971133.1    ML
  21448  AT1G01050     ntrc    ML_ntrc_dejan7   592207.0    ML
  23310  AT1G01050     ntrc ML_ntrc_Dejan_12R   347127.5    ML
  25204  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_20   131817.0    FL
  27134  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_39   560424.7    FL
  29064  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_33  9304183.7    FL
  30994  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_34   647452.4    FL
  32924  AT1G01050        m     FL_m_Dejan_21   712381.5    FL
  34854  AT1G01050        m     FL_m_Dejan_26  6089158.8    FL
  36784  AT1G01050        m     FL_m_Dejan_28 11341334.1    FL
  38714  AT1G01050        f     FL_f_Dejan_19 13140258.2    FL
  40644  AT1G01050        f     FL_f_Dejan_31 11256554.9    FL
  42574  AT1G01050        f     FL_f_Dejan_35  1621509.9    FL
  44504  AT1G01050        f      FL_f_Dejan37   392228.2    FL
  46434  AT1G01050     ntrc  FL_ntrc_Dejan_30  9069074.8    FL
  48364  AT1G01050     ntrc  FL_ntrc_Dejan_38   562403.6    FL
  50294  AT1G01050     ntrc   FL_ntrc_Dejan29   175258.6    FL
  79347  AT1G01050       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_41  2443625.6    LL
  81783  AT1G01050       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_43  8529143.7    LL
  84219  AT1G01050       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_49 11054552.6    LL
  86655  AT1G01050        m     LL_m_Dejan_44 14325152.0    LL
  89091  AT1G01050        m     LL_m_Dejan_45 13114486.4    LL
  91527  AT1G01050        m     LL_m_Dejan_54  8250430.1    LL
  93963  AT1G01050        f     LL_f_Dejan_47 12431354.5    LL
  96399  AT1G01050        f     LL_f_Dejan_48 11884118.5    LL
  98835  AT1G01050        f     LL_f_Dejan_53  8408509.1    LL
  101271 AT1G01050     ntrc  LL_ntrc_Dejan_46 12214783.1    LL
  103707 AT1G01050     ntrc  LL_ntrc_Dejan_50  1286828.3    LL
  106143 AT1G01050     ntrc  LL_ntrc_Dejan_42  1819043.9    LL

  plots<- list()

  pdf("TEST_boxplot.pdf")
  IDs<-unique(prot$Accession)
  for (i in 1:length(IDs)){
  temp <- prot[(prot$Accession)==IDs[i],]
  p<- ggplot(temp, aes(factor(genotype), value, fill = Light)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  ggtitle(as.character(i))
  plots[[i]] <- p
  #plots[[paste(i)]] = p
  #multiplot(plotlist = plots, cols = 1)
  }
  dev.off()
```

Comment: Add `print(p)` in your loop

Comment: hmm, when I set i=2 just t check and run the loop with print(p) i just got empty plots... also I have added the print(p) after ggtitle. didn't work

Comment: If you are using the above `prot` dataset, the resulting number of pages (and plots) in the pdf file is 1 (`Accession` has only 1 level). Try using a dataset with more levels for `Accession`. I made some test and works.

Comment: yes, I wrote in the description that prot is a signle accession subset. I run this code on data set with 1700 accessions. I have included the "prot" to show how my data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated a `prot` toy dataset with two levels for `Accession`. 
The code below prints 2 graphs on two pages of the `TEST_boxplot.pdf` file.
[Here](https://filebin.ca/3YS0b3ER7hz1/TEST_boxplot.pdf) is the file generated.

```
library(ggplot2)

prot1 <- read.table(text="
n  Accession genotype          variable      value Light
  966    AT1G01050       WT    ML_WT_Dejan_05   219971.1    ML
  2828   AT1G01050       WT    ML_WT_Dejan_06   286308.6    ML
  4690   AT1G01050       WT    ML_WT_Dejan_14  1177873.5    ML
  6552   AT1G01050        m     ML_m_Dejan_08   861982.0    ML
  8414   AT1G01050        m     ML_m_Dejan_10  3786163.0    ML
  10276  AT1G01050        m     ML_m_Dejan_11  1289267.7    ML
  12138  AT1G01050        f     ML_f_Dejan_01   400419.3    ML
  14000  AT1G01050        f     ML_f_Dejan_04   929297.2    ML
  15862  AT1G01050        f     ML_f_Dejan_09 12245991.9    ML
  17724  AT1G01050     ntrc  ML_ntrc_Dejan_02   785773.5    ML
  19586  AT1G01050     ntrc  ML_ntrc_Dejan_03   971133.1    ML
  21448  AT1G01050     ntrc    ML_ntrc_dejan7   592207.0    ML
  23310  AT1G01050     ntrc ML_ntrc_Dejan_12R   347127.5    ML
  25204  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_20   131817.0    FL
  27134  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_39   560424.7    FL
  29064  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_33  9304183.7    FL
  30994  AT1G01050       WT    FL_WT_Dejan_34   647452.4    FL
  32924  AT1G01050        m     FL_m_Dejan_21   712381.5    FL
  34854  AT1G01050        m     FL_m_Dejan_26  6089158.8    FL
  36784  AT1G01050        m     FL_m_Dejan_28 11341334.1    FL
  38714  AT1G01050        f     FL_f_Dejan_19 13140258.2    FL
  40644  AT1G01050        f     FL_f_Dejan_31 11256554.9    FL
  42574  AT1G01050        f     FL_f_Dejan_35  1621509.9    FL
  44504  AT1G01050        f      FL_f_Dejan37   392228.2    FL
  46434  AT1G01050     ntrc  FL_ntrc_Dejan_30  9069074.8    FL
  48364  AT1G01050     ntrc  FL_ntrc_Dejan_38   562403.6    FL
  50294  AT1G01050     ntrc   FL_ntrc_Dejan29   175258.6    FL
  79347  AT1G01050       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_41  2443625.6    LL
  81783  AT1G01050       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_43  8529143.7    LL
  84219  AT1G01050       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_49 11054552.6    LL
  86655  AT1G01050        m     LL_m_Dejan_44 14325152.0    LL
  89091  AT1G01050        m     LL_m_Dejan_45 13114486.4    LL
  91527  AT1G01050        m     LL_m_Dejan_54  8250430.1    LL
  93963  AT1G01050        f     LL_f_Dejan_47 12431354.5    LL
  96399  AT1G01050        f     LL_f_Dejan_48 11884118.5    LL
  98835  AT1G01050        f     LL_f_Dejan_53  8408509.1    LL
  101271 AT1G01050     ntrc  LL_ntrc_Dejan_46 12214783.1    LL
  103707 AT1G01050     ntrc  LL_ntrc_Dejan_50  1286828.3    LL
  106143 AT1G01050     ntrc  LL_ntrc_Dejan_42  1819043.9    LL
", header=T)

prot2 <- prot1
prot2$Accession <- "AT3G53620"
prot <- rbind(prot1,prot2)

plots <- list()   
pdf("TEST_boxplot.pdf", onefile=T)
IDs<-unique(prot$Accession)
for (i in 1:length(IDs)){
  temp <- prot[(prot$Accession)==IDs[i],]
  p<- ggplot(temp, aes(factor(genotype), value, fill = Light)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  ggtitle(as.character(i))
  plots[[i]] <- p
  print(p)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. [link](https://filebin.net/53km4lrehwoob9hu) `figure` take a look at the figures. I don't understand, why when I try to apply the code for my data it plots for each replicate a bar and not like in your example and in my example with out loop. O.o it's weird... I will try more but thank you

Comment: @tralala First: did you get now a pdf with multiple pages ? Second: could you post the output of `str(prot)` (where `prot` is your compete dataset) ?

Comment: thank you very much! I had problem with classes, happens, thank you for all you help. yes, I get pages and all what I had.